# How do you display a list of methods with UnrealEngine4 on Mac using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, unreal-engine4

For some reason when I type out Get-... I do not see a list of available functions. Instead I get a list of already written or used functions/data members.

Additionally, when I mouse over a written function (such as GetOwner for example) I do not get a description of what the method does or returns.

I'm pretty new to Xcode and Unreal Engine4 and I'm currently taking an online tutorial through Udemy. Just not quite sure how to get the two environments to communicate with each other well. [Here is the image of Get-- being typed out with no corresponding Get- methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMz65.png)

Comment: The reason Xcode struggles to load code completion is because Unreal names one of the directories: "Unreal Engine". When Xcode reads this it fails to follow the path because Xcode cannot read spaces in paths. Unfortunately, some versions of Unreal do not allow you to change the name of its directories. These issues can both be solved if you update to the current version of Unreal 4 (currently version 4.15.1). Upon doing this update your projects to 4.15 and then you will have code completion in Xcode.