# Importing Unreal Libraries into Xcode

Tags: xcode, osx-elcapitan, unreal-engine4

How do you import libraries from Unreal so that they're visible in the drop down bar that displays data members and functions from Unreal?

[See: Drop Down Function Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apnHr.png)

Comment: The solution I found is written here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523613/how-do-you-display-a-list-of-methods-with-unrealengine4-on-mac-using-xcode